# Set .htpasswd .htaccess for React build directory

Tags: reactjs, basic-authentication

I am using apache to host the `ReactProject`

I put `.htpasswd` and `.htaccess` in `ReactProject/build` directory, it works.

However once I did `npm run build` again.

Both files were deleted.

How can I prevent this??

Comment: Maybe store them somewhere else and copy them in the `build` script. E.g. run `cp ./conf/.htaccess ./conf/.htpasswd build`

Comment: I put `.htaccess` `.htpasswd` in `public` folder and it works than k you .

Answer (score 1):

you can put them in a public folder!

The reason the files were deleted is whenever you npm run build, public folder moved to build folder. ***It simply means if you do npm run build, the build folder is made by public folder.***